# remove period from key name in JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ejs

So, I'm not sure what's going on here and why you'd put a period in JSON key names.

The overview of what I am trying to do is pass a json response through ejs variables into a page template and get the data from that in individual fields.

The json response looks like this:

[image: JSON tree]

It's from prismic.io. (opening object bracket is cut off there, data is a child of the main object).

When I inject through EJS

```
<%= product.data.product.imgone2.value.main.url %>
```

I get an error like:

```
 Cannot read property 'imgone2' of undefined
```

Which, why would prismic do this?

Is there a way to fix that inline with EJS?

If not, how can I parse the JSON response with a javascript function to remove that?

In case you needed my route:

```
router.get('/product/:slug', function(req, res) {
//route params
  var slug = req.params.slug;
  var productResp; //scope up api response to pass to render()
  console.log(slug);
//api call
  Prismic.api("https://prismic.io/api").then(function(api) {
    return api.getByUID('product' , slug);
  }).then(function(response) {

    res.render('product-template', {
      product: response,
    })

  }, function(err) {
    console.log("Something went wrong: ", err);
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `product.data["product.imgone2"].value.main.url`?

Comment: Bracket Notation FTW!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> have you tried product.data["product.imgone2"].value.main.url?

From the official docs

To access a property like `object.property`

> property must be a **valid JavaScript identifier**, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

if the property is not a valid JavaScript identifier you have to use the bracket notation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been mentioned, use the bracket notation:

```
product.data["product.imgone2"].value.main.url
```

If this is not possible for whatever reason, you could run your object through the following function to "fix" the structure:

```js
//this will transform structures like these:
var a = {
  "data": {
    "product.imgone2": {
      "value": {
        "main.url": "yourMainUrl"
      },
      "another.value": "to show how this is handled"
    }
  }
}

//into these:
var b = nestKeysWithDots(a);
console.log(JSON.stringify(b, null, 2));

//wich now can be resolved by your paths, without worrying
console.log(
  "b.data.product.imgone2.value.main.url", 
  b.data.product.imgone2.value.main.url
);


//and the implementation:
function isObject(value){
  return typeof value === "object" && value !== null;
}

function nestKeysWithDots(source){
  return !isObject(source)? source:
    Array.isArray(source)? source.map(nestKeysWithDots):
    Object.keys(source).reduce((target, path) => {
      var value = nestKeysWithDots(source[path]);
      path.split(".").reduce((obj, key, index, array) => {
        if(index+1 === array.length){
          //last key
          obj[key] = value;
          return;
        }
        return key in obj && isObject(obj[key])?
          obj[key]:
          (obj[key] = {});
      }, target);
      return target;
    }, {});
}
```